# Create single object using new keyword

Tags: java, singleton

The below question is asked by 4th round interview by project director.

There is a class A . Any number of classes can be derived from A. Constraints is any subclass derived from A or A itself , I should be able to create only one object per class using new keyword. If I try to creating another object it will throw exception.

[image: Class B is derived class of A similarly class C, D, E are also derived classes. The number of class is not limited. Any number of classes can be derived.]

Class B is derived class of A similarly class C, D, E are also derived classes. The number of class is not limited. Any number of classes can be derived.

The logic of restriction must be inside the class heirarchy not inside the main class.

Sample code of main class.

```
A obj1 = new A();  // object should create
A obj2 = new A();   // exception should throw
E Obj3 = new E();  //object should create
E obj4 = new E();   //Exception should throw
```

Comment: @Logan that could have been work but ,class A has sub class also and when a sub class object is created constructor of A will be called.

Comment: I hope you mentioned that this should be using in a singleton instead. A constructor should not need to know if it was already called once, especially in a inherited context.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In class A: have a static set of class. Each time the constructor of A is invoked, use this.getClass() to acquire the actual class that wants to be instantiated (keep in mind that any sub class has to call a super constructor first).

If the class is stored in the set, throw that exception. If not, then store the class.

```
public class A {

private static final Set<Class<? extends A>> INSTANCE_HOLDER = new HashSet<>();

public A() {
    if (INSTANCE_HOLDER.contains(this.getClass()))
        throw new RuntimeException("can't create more than one instance.");

    INSTANCE_HOLDER.add(this.getClass());
}
}
```

This should be enough to get you started.

For the record: although this should work, it seems like a rather odd idea. If you need singleton objects, rather look into using enums for example. That will prevent all the subtle issues, for example due multiple threads creating objects.

Or, as pointed out by the comment: what about the life time of these objects? You could use a map to ensure that references to your singletons are kept.

But in the end, all of this sounds like violations of the single responsibility principle.

Comment: Especially since this would required to implement `finalize` to release the class from the `Set` when the GC collect what it can but of course I would not add that kind of logic in a `Finalize` method, so unless the `Set` become a `Map<Class, A>` to be a "Mutliton` (Multi + singleton ;) ), this would never be usable.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that by storing a static reference to a collection holding instantiated classes (could be any data structure that works), then checking it in the constructor to avoid multiple instantiations:

```
class A {
    private static Set<String> instantiatedClasses = new HashSet<>();

    A() {
        super();

        if (instantiatedClasses.contains(getClass().getName())) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Cannot create multiple instances of " +getClass().getName());
        }

        instantiatedClasses.add(this.getClass().getName());
    }
}

class B extends A {
}
```

And when that's tested:

```
A a = new A();
System.out.println("Created a: " + a);
try {
    a = new A();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

a = new B();
System.out.println("Created b: " + a);
a = new B();
```

An output like this is produced:

```
Created a: stackoverflow.A@506e1b77
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create multiple instances of stackoverflow.A
    at stackoverflow.A.<init>(Main.java:32)
    at stackoverflow.Main.main(Main.java:14)
Created b: stackoverflow.B@9807454
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create multiple instances of stackoverflow.B
    at stackoverflow.A.<init>(Main.java:32)
    at stackoverflow.B.<init>(Main.java:40)
    at stackoverflow.Main.main(Main.java:21)
```

This is just exploiting the fact that a superclass's constructor is always invoked on instance creation for subclasses. And this will work even for arbitrary inheritance depths.

There are alternative ways of keeping track of classes that have been instantiated, one of which is storing the class, but I believe the necessary part is checking the type in the constructor (where the runtime classes can be seen, and before too late to prevent successful instantiation)

Comment: You want a funny workaround for your solution ? `a = new A(){};`. Now, can't this still be seen as a `A` class... not really.

Comment: @AxelH Yeah... But that doesn't break the answer to the interview question, because `new A(){}` is effectively a different subclass. So only one instance of it is created.

Comment: Totally agree. But with this, I can still generate as many instances I want. I could loop to generate an "infinite" amount of anonymous class until the `Set` overload. And since this isn't the same class, I don't believe it would be correct to simply refuse any `getClass().isAnonymous()`. That's just to point that the question itself isn't ideal and that this would requires some boundaries.

Comment: @AxelH That's right. The question was probably just meant to test problem solving skills. This is one good example of a useless problem to have... **But you cannot create multiple inner class instances in a loop** (It's in fact the same class `Main$1`). You can only go around it by actually generating classes dynamically (such as by using javassist).

Comment: I didn't knew that ! (Never had the idea to use it to be honest ;) )

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static instance in `A` and then in the constructor check if an instance exists and if yes then throw an exception , if it does not then create an object. I am assuming that there is only one object of any class that is either A or a subclass of A. If you mean to say that there should be only instance for each subclass and `A` , then you may need to create a static HashMap with class Names as the key in `A` and then check if an instance exists for the particular class by checking for the className from the HashMap.